# Cannot initialize MockMvc in Spock test class

Tags: spring-boot, testing, spock, mockmvc

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/task")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Validated
@Slf4j
public class TaskController {

    private final TaskService taskService;
    private final TaskMapper taskMapper;

    // Mapping methods 
}
```

```
@SpringBootTest
class TaskControllerSpec extends Specification {

    @MockBean
    def taskService
    @Shared
    def taskController = new TaskController(taskService, {})
    @Shared
    MockMvc mockMvc
    @Shared
    private int id
    @Shared
    private UpdateTaskRequest updateTaskRequest
    @Shared
    private CreateTaskRequest createTaskRequest

    void setupSpec() {
        mockMvc = standaloneSetup(taskController)
        updateTaskRequest = new UpdateTaskRequest("UpdatedTask", LocalDate.now().plusDays(7), null, TaskState.IN_PROGRESS)
        createTaskRequest = new CreateTaskRequest("TestTask", null, null, TaskState.TODO)

        def taskResponse = mockMvc.perform(post("/api/task")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(asJsonString(createTaskRequest)))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andReturn()

        id = taskResponse.response.contentAsString.toInteger()
    }
    // Tests
}
```

First I tried annotation `@WemMvcTest(TaskController.class)` and `@Autowired` on MockMvc mockMvc, but it didn't work, `mockMvc` was always null.

Then I `standaloneSetup()`, as in code I provided here, but got error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.example.taskmanager.web.TaskControllerSpec.standaloneSetup() is applicable for argument types: (com.example.taskmanager.web.TaskController) values: [com.example.taskmanager.web.TaskController@790132f7]
```

Comment: You left out the method `standaloneSetup` that is the cause for the exception, please add it, or did you forget a static import? Furthermore, using `@Shared` with Spring has some [caveats](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.3/all_in_one.html#_shared_fields_injection).